# Using Linq to extract data from a Table

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a table as shown in the picture below. I need to extract a list from the table where it lists it on the basis of the country. And there is no repetition of the country. So for example, China would appear only once, its total pay would be added, and its total Debt would be added and all other column would be added respectively. So It should look like something below:

```
Country --- Totay Pay---Total Debt--- NetAmount

China--     (3.1+4.2)B--- (2.0+2.0)B----(8+4)B

India--     

Russia---
```

I would prefer if we can use LINQ expressions. I tried using GroupBy and other operators but can't get my head around.

[image: Table of Data]

Comment: can you post what you've tried?

Comment: you don't want to extract it from the paper, right? :P

Comment: @dom, he's tried pen and paper cant you tell?!? ;)

Comment: @christiandev lol, we're getting clever now.  C_sharp, so you want to sum the values grouping by country?

Comment: @Christiandev good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) operator is good direction - you should group by country and sum other values using [one of its overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549393%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that:

> Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key selector function and creates a result value from each group and its key.

Assuming data like:

```
var data = new List<Data>()
{
    new Data() { Country = "China", Index = 2, TotalPay = 3.1M, TotalDebt = 2.0M, NetAmount = 8.0M},
    new Data() { Country = "India", Index = 4, TotalPay = 2.1M, TotalDebt = 3.0M, NetAmount = 9.0M},
    new Data() { Country = "China", Index = 8, TotalPay = 5.1M, TotalDebt = 4.0M, NetAmount = 10.0M},
};
```

you can write:

```
var results = data.GroupBy(x => x.Country, (key, elements) => new Data()
    {
        Country = key,
        Index = elements.Sum(v => v.Index),
        TotalPay = elements.Sum(v => v.TotalPay),
        TotalDebt = elements.Sum(v => v.TotalDebt),
        NetAmount = elements.Sum(v => v.NetAmount)
    });
```